# Show author post count in sidebar - Variable

Tags: posts, author

I need to display something of a mini author statistic in my sidebar on the single posts page. I'm using the PHP code widget, to allow me to insert PHP code into a widget. What I've done is run a loop in the sidebar like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <ul>
        <li>


<?php echo 'Posts made: ' . get_usernumposts(4); ?>

<p>
Author Rank: <?php the_author_meta('user_level'); ?>
<br>
Author's Name: <?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?>
<br>
User ID: <?php the_author_meta('ID'); ?>
</p>


        </li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

So that shows the number of user posts for the author ID '4'. And yes, the function still works properly though it's deprecated.

I obviously need something a bit more dynamic, as the author data varies post to post, so a static ID is not going to do the trick. I've no idea why there isn't something like

```
<?php the_author_meta('post_count'); ?>
```

I suppose that would be too convenient. I've seen a lot of queries that select post counts in various ways, all of which either aren't what I need or do not work in or outside of my loop in the sidebar.

My first thought, though I am no expert with PHP is to assign a variable to the value of usernumposts that pulls the data from the value of

```
<?php the_author_meta('ID'); ?>
```

I don't know if this is possible at all, but it would certainly achieve my goals. So can this be done? How? And if not - what are my other options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of posts published by a user i found the solution was to call `count_user_posts()`, passing in the appropriate user id.

```
<?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta('ID') ); ?>
```

In translation ready form.

```
<?php printf( 'Posts made: %d', count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta('ID') ) ); ?>
```

Storage in a variable.

```
<?php $user_post_count = count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta('ID') ); ?>
```

Comment: Codex says function is deprecated in favor of [`count_user_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts).

Comment: Hey thanks - I was trying to find which function took its place. I appreciate that!

Comment: `get_usernumposts` will actually call `count_user_posts` anyway, the only difference should be that calling the former produces a deprecated message.

Comment: Updated the answer to use the newer function and extended the examples given.