# Get total post from an author

Tags: posts, author

I want to display some data from an author on my loop with this code:

- Avatar

  ```
  <?php echo get_avatar( $q->ID, 255 ); ?>
  ```
- Name.

  ```
  <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?>
  ```
- Total post.

  ```
  <?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta($q->ID) ); ?>
  ```

Full code:

```
 <?php 
        $number     = $count_post;
        $paged      = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $offset     = ($paged - 1) * $number;
        $users      = get_users();
        $query      = get_users('&offset='.$offset.'&number='.$number);
        $total_users = count($users);
        $total_query = count($query);
        foreach($query as $q) { ?>

 - Avatar
 <?php echo get_avatar( $q->ID, 255 ); ?>
 - Name.
  <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?>
 - Total post.
    <?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta($q->ID) ); ?>

    <?php }
 ?>
```

The avatar and the author's name is displayed, but the total post failed to display.

Anybody know how to resolve the problem?
Really appreciate for any idea.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the_author_posts()** doesn't accept any parameters see the following codex page for more info:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts#Parameters

*** *UPDATED* ***

Someone else had posted a VERY similar question. This should solve your problem:

[Show author post count in sidebar - Variable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/show-author-post-count-in-sidebar-variable?rq=1)

Comment: Just edited, change to <?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta($q->ID) ); ?> but still not work

Comment: What is your `$q` query? Is that a post/page query or is that a user account query?

Comment: just edit, added the full code. Please kindly check.

Comment: I read the link you gave me, doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do me a favor, simply echo $q->ID and let me know what it returns. That will be the first step towards solving your problem.

Comment: Just change from <?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta($q->ID) ); ?> to <?php echo count_user_posts( $q->ID ); ?> and everything work fine. Thanks, Ryan.

Comment: Awesome, dude. Glad I could be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just:

```
<?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts( $q->ID ); ?>
```

Assuming that `$q->ID` is your author's ID. [count_user_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts)

Comment: just edit, added the full code.

Answer (score 0):

This code will count users posts count and then show it.
You have to pass author id as variable `$authorID`

```php
<?php printf(__('%s', 'themetextdoamin'),  count_user_posts($authorID, "post")); ?>
```